# How to select single item from a GraphQL query and pass it in to Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to figure out how to select a single item from a query, but I'm getting stuck. I have a list of items (pokemons), but when I click on one I will like to select this particular item (pokemon), rerun a query with the selected item so I can get all its details.

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/graphql-apollo-example-fkqb2) with the example.

And here is some of the code:

```
 // graphql queries 

import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const GET_ALL_POKEMONS = gql`
  {
    Pokemons(first: 151) {
      id
      name
      image
      types(first: 1) {
        name
      }
      abilities {
        name
      }
      stats {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
`

const GET_POKEMON_DETAILS = gql`
  query PokemonDetails($pokemonName: String!) {
    Pokemon(name: $pokemonName) {
      name
      types {
        name
      }
      abilities {
        name
      }
      stats {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
`

export { GET_ALL_POKEMONS, GET_POKEMON_DETAILS 

}



// Pokemon Detail view
function PokemonDetails(props): ReactNode {
  const { pokemonName } = props.name

  // This is the Query I will like to use to get a detail view of my pokemon:
  // Having problems hooking it up to the onClick

  const { loading, error, data, networkStatus } = useQuery(GET_POKEMON_DETAILS, {
    variables: { name: pokemonName },
  })

  if (loading) return <Paragraph>Loading...</Paragraph>
  if (error) return <Paragraph textColor="red">Error: {error.message}</Paragraph>

  return <div>{/* Need to put the pokemon details here */}</div>
}


// This gives me a single Pokemon


function PokemonItem(props: PokemonItemProps): ReactNode {
  const { pokemon } = props

  function onHandleSave() {
    console.log(`I was save: ${pokemon.name}`)
  }

  function onHandleSelect() {
    console.log(`I was selected: ${pokemon.name}`)
  }

  return (
    <CardArticle>
      <Avatar alt="pokemon-image" src={pokemon.image} />
      <Paragraph>ID: {pokemon.id}</Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>Name: {pokemon.name}</Paragraph>

      {/* [TODO]: Need to either use lodash or a `.map()` for the following data */}
      <Paragraph>Type: {pokemon.types.name}</Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>Abilities: {pokemon.abilities.name}</Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>Stats: {pokemon.stats.name}</Paragraph>

      <Button onClick={onHandleSelect}>Select this Pokemon</Button>
      <Button onSubmit={onHandleSave}>Save this Pokemon</Button>
    </CardArticle>
  )
}

// This gives me a list of all my Pokemons
function PokemonList(props: PokemonListProps): ReactNode {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_POKEMONS)  // This works

  if (loading) return <Paragraph>Loading...</Paragraph>
  if (error) return <Paragraph textColor="red">Error: {error.message}</Paragraph>

  return (
    <CardsSection>
      {data.Pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
        <PokemonItem key={pokemon.id} pokemon={pokemon} />
      ))}
    </CardsSection>
  )
}
```